# Show a div once reached another

Tags: jquery

I have a site where I want to fade in and fade out the content div once I reached the section.

Please see the example:

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
}
.content{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
section{
  height: 200px;
  width:400p;
}
#s1{
  background: red;
}
#s2{
  background: blue;
}
#s3{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#s1"><p>Section One</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="#s2"><p>Section Two</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="#s3"><p>Section Three</p></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="s1"  data-index="0">
    <div class="content"> 
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="s2" data-index="1">
    <div class="content"> 
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="s3" data-index="2">
    <div class="content"> 
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I would like to run this code same on when I click anchors or scroll to the sections.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and explain what errors you're getting

Comment: I can say that I have tried nothing yet, I am not very good yet in the JQuery. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid SO is not here to code solutions for you from scratch, for that there are sites such as https://www.elance.com/. Start at the beginning, if you run into problems SO users will only be to happy to assist with ***specific*** problems with your code

Comment: I got the point, will be trying to figure it out somehow and post some code as soon as I get something similar. Thanks :)